# Can I prevent hyperlinks in messages being clickable on Android?

Tags: browser, sms

My father has a Samsung Galaxy A6 phone running Android (don't remember the version on the top of my head, but I guess 8 or 9). From time to time he gets these scam SMS with hyperlinks, and now during the holiday season he is getting many more. He has dementia and I'm afraid that he will click on these hyperlinks.

Currently I periodically connect to his phone and delete any scam SMS I see, but now I've come up with the idea that maybe there is a way to disable hyperlinks from being clickable altogether. He rarely gets messages anyway, so there wouldn't be any legitimate need for him to click on hyperlinks. I don't want to disable or uninstall the web browser, because he surfs the web on his phone. It's just from the SMS app I would like to disable hyperlinks.

Comment: There are two solutions I can think of now. 1) find an SMS app that allows disabling hyperlink clicking. You'd have to search and try a couple SMS apps in Play Store, or try asking this as a question at [softwarerecs.se]. 2) Other option is to isolate the SMS app. You can try running the SMS app only in Work profile, and remove all browsers or don't install any browser in Work profile. This way, even if your Father clicks on a hyperlink the Android would have no way of loading it in a browser because it doesn't exist.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have time to write an answer right now, but if you don't get good answers, ping me in a few days, and I'll hopefully have time to write up an answer.  The solution I have in mind may not be perfect, but could likely help.

Comment: Related on SoftwareRecs.SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/81470/520

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket You asked me to ping you if I didn't get good answers. I'm interested in hearing your solution, if you have the time.

Comment: Thank you for pinging me.  Unfortunately, I'm still swamped.  I'm going to add this to my list, but in full disclosure, it's a long list!  Feel free to ping me again (I truly don't mind).